# Plaxo and Facebook's logo on Google's OpenID confirmation page

Tags: facebook, openid, branding, plaxo

Cheers,

after seeing Stack Overflow's excellent implementation of OpenID, and after seeing what great job Google did with OpenID, I implemented it on a web app I'm working on. During my research I ran into Plaxo as another great RP.

Recently, Facebook added some rudimentary OpenID support. It's apparently used for completely different purposes that ordinarily: I didn't find a way to *log in* with OpenID there. Yet, there's one thing that caught my attention: on Google-hosted UI, they had a Facebook logo, and a bit different heading. At first I thought this might be because of the new "popup extension" recently designed precisely because of Facebook. However I edited the authorization URL and removed reference to the popup extension, and the icon was still there. When I wrote the extension support, it didn't add the icon.

I looked around, and Plaxo's got their icon on Google's auth page as well.

Although this might be a result of business deal between Google and Plaxo, and Google and Facebook, it might not be the case. So I am wondering: Does anyone have idea how to add this icon?

*n.b. I've [inquired about this](http://groups.google.com/group/google-federated-login-api/browse_thread/thread/6aa1975a5eece968) on Google's Federated Login API group, and received no response. I've also repeatedly did searching on the internet; apparently there isn't many people who noticed this and who are sufficiently interested in this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a white list of RPs that it's doing experimental extra features with.  I don't think placing the logo on Google's login page is offered generally yet.

Comment: I suspected it might be something like this. Here's a tick for the effort, anyway.